# Does AutoEventWireup="true" cause dynamic compilation in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I've precompiled my application out of frustration with the dynamic compilation and shadow files often not working, requiring clearing the ASP.NET temp files, learning about malformed tags and run time, etc.

Does AutoEventWireup cause run time compilation or does the auto event wireup happen at compile or pre-compile time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that AutoEventWireup happens at run time, when the page is constructed reflection is used to 'wire-up' the events dynamically based on their names (it searches for ALL event names on the page), rather that having to hook them up in code.